# selenium get element by xpath based on two frames

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a problem.  I need to log in to a website and automatically download some prices.  I used selenium with python and managed to log in.  But I am having a hard time figuring out how to hover over the "Settlements" tab, then once I hover over the 'settlements' tab, a "settlement info' tab shows up.  Then when I hover over the 'settlement' tab, a 'view' tab shows up.  I need to click the view tab.  I also have this issue of having two different frames.  Heres the html of the website:

```
<html>
  <frameset name = "frameset" frameborder="no" noresize="">
    <frame name="nav" src="/miso/header/header.do;jsessionid=2d..!" frameboarder="no" no resize="" scrolling="no">
      <html>
        <body background = "/miso/images/hdrbackgroundslvr.gif >
           <table width ..>
           <div id="xclock1"..>
           <div id="tab1">
           <div id="tab2">
              <table width="115">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class='normalHeaderTabs" id="tab2TableDetail" style="background: url ("https://markets.midwesiso.org/MISO/images/hdrTabNormal.gif");">..</td>
                     <p id="tab2_p" style="color: rgb(2555,255,255);" onmouseover="this.style.color=">Settlements</p
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>
            </div>
    <frame name="ContentFrame"
     src="/MISO/common/blank.html;jsessionid=2bC6h1hLNJwrN..." frameborder="no" scrolling="auto">
        <html>
          <head>..</head>
          <body>
            <table witdh='735' ..></table>
            <div id='tab1flyover0" onmouseover='document.getElementbyID('tab1flyover0DivShim')
              <table width="160" cellspace="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td aligh="left" id="tab2_tab2flyover0tableDetail0" valign="center" onclick='parent.frames[0].changeTopTabs('tab2TableDetail');parent.frames[0].changeContentFrame('/MISO/vss/view.do?cmd=view');">
                      <p id="tab2_tab2flyover0text0" style="color:black;">View</p>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
                 </table>
               </div>
            <div id="tab1flyover2" style="left" onmouseover='document..'
            <iframe id='tab1flyover1DivShim'>
            <div id="tab2" onmouseover='document.getElementById("tab2DivShim");document.getElementByid('tab2').style.visibility='visible';"onmouseout="..'
            <table width="160">
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td height="20" id="tab2_tab2cell0"; onmouseover="document.getElementByID('tab2flyover0') onmouseout='document.getElementByID("tab2_tab2Cell0).style.backgroundcolor='#C0CoCo';document.getElementbyId('tab2flyover0').style.visibility='hidden'
                   <p id='tab2_tab2flyover0" >Settlement Info</p>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
            <
```

Now, how can I choose the settlements tab?  I have tried this method and it works, but it creates problems down the road for me when I want to hover over the elements.  Please help:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


#set directory where files will be downloaded
iedriver = 'H://work/IEDriverServer.exe'
driver = webdriver.Ie(iedriver) #establish internet explorer as website

#website where we download files from
url = 'https://markets.midwestiso.org/MISO/'
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
time.sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame('nav')
settlements = driver.find_element_by_id("tab2_p")

driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("ContentFrame")

settlement_info = driver.find_element_by_id("tab2_tab2flyover0")
view = driver.find_element_by_id("tab2_tab2flyover0text0")
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("nav")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(settlements).perform() #this successfully goes to the settlements tab and hovers over it.  

driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("ContentFrame")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(settlement_info).perform()
#actions.click(view).
```

There is no error, but the mouse is not hovering over the "settlement info" and finally the "view" tab.  Can someone please help?  Thanks

Comment: `it creates problems down the road for me when I want to hover over the elements` - what kind of problems, could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Basically there are two submenus when I hover over the "settlement tab"..  When I hover over settlement tab, then a "settlement info" tab shows up.  Upon hovering over settlement info tab, then view tab shows which I want to click.  Switching frames makes it complicated when using selenium since I have to switch from one frame to another.  then to another and back.

Comment: Ok I will add the contents of the "content frame" and explain exactly what I want.  give me a sec

Comment: Is that better? @alecxe

Comment: A frame creates a different document/DOM Tree, xpath can only work on elements in the same document/DOM tree. If you really want to avoid switching frames, you will have to  somehow merge the documents. That is not going to be the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *if you need to access elements in iframes - you just have to switch to them.*

In your case, the reason why selenium cannot find the `ContentFrame` frame is that at the moment of the search, you are still in the context of the `nav` frame - *switch to the [default content](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_default_content) and then switch to the `ContentFrame` frame*:

```
driver.swtich_to.default_content()
driver.swtich_to.frame("ContentFrame")
```

Comment: oh I see.  is it possible to do it by xpath?

Comment: @rajn nope, xpaths are still gonna operate in the current context of a frame or default content.

Comment: I see.  thanks.  So in this case, the method I used along with your suggestion would help me navigate to the "settlement info" tab and then finally to "view" tab?

Comment: @rajn yes, every time you need to locate an element on this particular page - look in which context you are and in which context this element is in. I understand that with multiple frames it's gonna be switching back and forth, but that's what you have to do.

Comment: I did as you recommended.  But am having trouble hovering over the "settlements" tab and then the "settlemnts info" tab.  I switched the drivers in the action chains but still not working.  Can you please help?  thanks

Comment: can you see my modified code above as I have a new problem now  How do i hover over the elements based on the action chains?